# How do I request feedback on my paper?

Tags: publications, email, feedback

I have written this paper and I would like to ask, via email, from some professors in other universities to give me feedback. How is the best way to write such a request? First, what should I write in the email subject box? Then, how do I write the body of email?

Comment: Related: [What are the strategies for getting feedback on articles?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3271/14341)

Answer (score 1):

Professors are busy people. If you send a random professor with whom you've never had any contact a paper and ask him or her to review it and provide feedback, odds are that you will never hear back from them, because they will ignore the request.

If you want a better response, you will need to cultivate a relationship with the faculty members over a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in research career and hasn't had enough relationship to be welcomed to ask for feedback, then your manuscript will likely be perceived to have low quality by busy people. In my experience you should ask it on a forum (Stack Exchange or Reddit), because your level is perfectly suited to ask there. In general, a quality post is not a wall-length post with a question "what do you think", but a post **clearly** explains an **entanglement** you found, because who can see that are indeed serious with it.

In my observation, Stack Exchange is best to ask for solution, Reddit is best for giving solution.

Comment: Would the user who raised the Low Quality Post flag explain why this is low quality except a few typos?

Comment: I didn't flag this, though my guess would be the perception that it didn't answer the question.  The question appears to be about how to get feedback on a manuscript while this answer's more about how to get questions answered.

Comment: Was that how this answer was intended?  I mean it sounds like this answer's saying that Stack Exchange is a good place to get feedback on a manuscript.

Comment: @scaaahu can I see which posts of mine are flagged by what reasons?

Comment: @Nat yes, because your manuscript will be perceived to has low quality by the busy people?

Comment: @Ooker https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/62585